# Blank data inserting into MySQL database on refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

Blank data added on refresh to mysql database how to get rid of??

**Here is my code**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3bU0f9cR-ehM1E1Z1MzWHBNQkU/edit

Comment: The link shows me "This file does not exist" (in German).

Comment: Your link doesn't have anything. Also, you have given nothing to identify your problem.

Comment: check now i updated the link

Comment: @Aufziehvogel check again dude

Answer (score 0):

Each web-developer have to follow 2 strict rules

1. All requests that change server stat (i.e. alter database) have to be performed using POST method
2. After processing POST method request, a GET method redirect have to be done

so, for example, add these lines after insert

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
exit;
```

Comment: **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started**